# Hide/show elements using only Javascript without messing with DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Just wondering, is it possible to use only Javascript to hide/show elements without using "style" method? So I won't have to use any inline CSS in my HTML element. Or even, how does jQuery perform the hide/show event in its core?

Comment: jQuery changes the `style` attribute. Changing the CSS (whether directly or by adding a class) is the only way to change an elements appearance. You could show/hide elements by adding/removing them from the DOM but then you have to keep track of where you pulled them from and how to put them back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adding/removing a CSS class with both Javascript and Jquery.

Assuming this is the CSS class that gets added to the DOM element:

```
.hide { display: none}
```

Then you can use:

**Javascript v1**

```
function toggleClass(element, className){
  if (!element || !className){
    return;
  }

  var classString = element.className, nameIndex = classString.indexOf(className);
  if (nameIndex == -1) {
    classString += ' ' + className;
  }
  else {
    classString = classString.substr(0, nameIndex) + classString.substr(nameIndex+className.length);
  }
  element.className = classString;
}
```

**Javascript v2** (`classList.toggle()` supported by most modern browsers)

```
document.getElementById('foo').classList.toggle('hide');
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#foo').toggleClass('hide');
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does it by manipulating styles.

There are many ways to manipulate the DOM:

- manipulating the style attribute
- adding/removing a class with some styles
- just plain adding/removing an element from the DOM itself
- etc.

But it all involves manipulating the DOM in some fashion, because that *is* what the browser renders.

Answer (score 1):

You can toggle CSS classes that will hide / show the elements for you. You have to manipulate the DOM in any case, though.

```
.hidden {
   display: none;
}

document.getElementById("foo").className += " hidden";
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's do this using pure JavaScript.

`removeElement()` removes the element from DOM using [Node.removeChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) and also saves both the element and its position in the DOM, in case you want to put it back.

`insertElement()`, as you would guess, puts the element back where it was using [Node.insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore).

You can keep track of the removed elements in the `removedElements` object.

No CSS/inline-style modification.

```js
var removedElements = {};

function removeElement(id) {
  var obj = {
    element : document.getElementById(id),
    parent : document.getElementById(id).parentNode,
    nextSibling : document.getElementById(id).nextElementSibling,
  };
  removedElements[id] = obj;
  obj.parent.removeChild(obj.element);
}

function insertElement(id) {
  var obj = removedElements[id];
  obj.parent.insertBefore(obj.element, obj.nextSibling);
  delete removedElements[id];
}

removeElement("h1");
insertElement("h1");
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1 id="h1">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p id="p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```